# How can I get a list of languages which are enabled by the user in their Android device?

Tags: java, android

How can I get a list of the languages which the user has added to their device? In the example below, the user has gone to device settings and added two languages. How can I programmatically get this list?

[image: **List of languages added by user on their phone**]

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
LocaleListCompat llc = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration());
for (int i=0; i<llc.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(llc.get(i).getDisplayLanguage());
}
```

This has backward compatiblity with versions. And `llc` will have all selected language by the user.

If you want full list of supported languages you will get it using `Locale`

```
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        System.out.println("HELLO " + locale.getDisplayLanguage());
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

On Android 7.0 (API level 24) and above, you should call [`LocaleList.getDefault()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/LocaleList.html#getDefault()).  On earlier versions of Android, there was only an option to pick one language, which you can get via `Locale.getDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. Is there any other way? Reason I ask is because my Application's minimum API support requirement is 19.

Comment: Since there's only an option to pick one language before API 24, you can create a method that checks the device's API version and uses either `Locale.getDefault()` on pre-24, and `LocaleList.getDefault()` on 24 and above, then puts the results from that into a list that you can read on any API version.

Answer (score 4):

For languages selected by user -

```
private fun getSystemLocale(): String {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return LocaleList.getDefault().get(0).getLanguage();
    } else {
        return Locale.getDefault.getLanguage();
    }
}
```

If you want to get the selected language of your device with below options:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States) 
Locale.getDefault().toString()          ---> en_US
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()---> English
Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag()     ---> en-US
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version. This is almost the same as suggested by (Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala). Only with sorting and first capital letter.

```
val language = ArrayList<String>()
val llc = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration)
for (i in 0 until llc.size()) {
    
    language.add(llc[i].displayLanguage.substring(0,1).uppercase(Locale.getDefault()) + llc[i].displayLanguage.substring(1)

}
val set: Set<String> = HashSet(language)
language.clear()
language.addAll(set)
language.sort()
```

It will turn out like this: English French Russian Ukrainian and so on

Answer (score -1):

Here is the API to get all the available locales of your device.

public static Locale[] getAvailableLocales ()
For more information please check this public link : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales()

Comment: This is incorrect - these are the _installed_ locales, not the ones that the user has selected.

Comment: He is right. This function returns al available languages. Not the installed languages